# Disable deduplication by email address in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are using Salesforce contact id as subscriber key within Marketing cloud.

For one of the Journeys, we have duplicate contacts in our subscriber list (contacts with same subscriberkey and same email) where we are using combined primary key (Sno(Unique) + SubscriberKey) for Operational/Transactional Comms. Upon activating the journey, it's deduplicating by email address which is not our requirement as the subscribers must receive multiples transactional emails.

I tried using Guided Send, it works absolutely fine.

Is there any way where we can avoid deduplication by email address in Journey Builder?

Comment: I don't believe that contacts are being de-duplicated. I suspect that you have not set the Contact Entry Mode to 'Re-entry anytime' in the Journey Settings. Can you confirm this? I'm not sure what you mean by a combined Primary Key. Is this your Contact Key value?

Comment: Yes, I did miss the contact entry mode to 'Re-entry anytime'. However, the issue has been resolved now.

Comment: Are you able to answer your question to reflect what the solution was, for the benefit of others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating journey, in settings, select Contact Entry to "Re-entry anytime" to send multiple emails to the same contact.

I have tried this and it's working fantastic.